# How to print the result of a State Monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads

Is it possible to print the result of a state monad in Haskell?

I'm trying to understand state monads and in a book I have been following supplies the code below for creating a state monad, but I am struggling with this topic as I am unable to view the process visually i.e. see the end result.

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s)}

instance Monad (State s) where  
    return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)  
    (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                        (State g) = f a  
                                    in  g newState
```

Comment: “How to print a State Monad” is a completely different question from “how to print the _result_ of a state monad”, at least if I understand the former as printing of _a `State` action_ and the latter as _printing the result of executing a `State` action once_. Which do you mean?

Comment: @leftaroundabout result sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've supplied defines the *kind* of thing `State s a` is. And it also says that `State s` is a monad - that is, the kind of thing `State s` is conforms to the `Monad` typeclass/interface. This means you can bind one `State s` computation to another (as long as the type `s` is the same in each).

So your situation is analogous to that of someone who has defined the kind of thing that a `Map` is, and has also written code that says a `Map` conforms to such and such interfaces, but who doesn't have any maps, and hasn't yet run any computation with them. There's nothing to print then.

I take it you want to see the result of evaluating or executing your state actions, but you have not defined any actual state actions yet, nor have you called `runState` (or `evalState` or `execState`) on them. Don't forget you also need to supply an initial state to run the computation.

So maybe start by letting `s` and `a` be some particular types. E.g. let `s` be `Int` and let `a` be `Int`. Now you could go write some fns, e.g. `f :: Int -> (Int, Int)`, and `g :: Int -> (Int, Int)`. Maybe one function decrements the state, returning the new state and value, and another function increments the state, returning the new state and value. Then you could make a `State Int Int` out of `f` by wrapping it in the `State` constructor. And you could use `>>=` to chain as many state actions together as you like. Finally, you can use `runState` on this, to get the resulting value and resulting state, as long as you also supply an initial state (e.g. 0).

Comment: @liminalishit Thank you a lot your answer it is really helpful! I have made a function f to increment the state. I am bit unsure how to do the chain part sorry, would it be possible for you to show me an example please. Thank you

Comment: Let `f = \x -> (x+1, x+1)`, and let `g = State (f) >>= State (f)`. This represents a state action that increments state twice. `runState g 0` should return `(2,2)`. Equivalently, if `h = \x -> return (x+1, x+1)`, and j = `StateT (h) >>= StateT (h)`, then `runStateT h 0` returns `(2,2)`. This might give you a feel for how the `State` monad works. But building state actions using `get` `put` and `modify`, from a package like `mtl` or `transformers`, is usually how you will use the `State` monad, and really resembles the imperative style that you might be used to from an imperative language.

Answer (score 4):

It is generally not possible to print functions in a meaningful way. If the domain of the function is small, you can import [`Data.Universe.Instances.Show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-reverse-instances-1.0/docs/Data-Universe-Instances-Show.html) from the [universe-reverse-instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-reverse-instances) package to get a `Show` instance that prints a lookup table that is semantically equivalent to the function. With that module imported, you could simply add `deriving Show` to your `newtype` declaration to be able to print `State` actions over small state spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the result you want, and if you're just debugging:

```
import Debug.Trace
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

action :: State [Int] ()
action = do
  put [0]
  modify (1:)
  modify (2:)
  get >>= traceShowM
  modify (3:)
  modify (4:)
  get >>= traceShowM
```

Comment: thank you but I get the error not in scope for put, modify, modify, get, modify, modify, get?

Comment: This is using functions provided by the library accessible by importing Control.Monad.Trans.State

Comment: Thank you, I get an error for "Ambiguous occurrence 'State' It could refer to either 'Main.State', or 'Control.Monad.Trans.State.State' "? @Gurkenglas

Comment: State is defined already in the transformers package and you'll have to comment out your version of it if you want to use the package's version. Alternatively you can reimplement get and put

Comment: I get the error (Show (State [Int] ())) when running the action function?

Comment: When you write `action` into ghci, it tries to convert it into a String, as defined by its `Show` instance, and show you that. Only it doesn't have a Show instance, because there's no general way to convert a function into a String. You'll have to apply `action` to some state and will get the state and/or output that results: `runState action [1..3]` for both, `evalState action []` for the output, `execState action [5,1]` for the state. Of course, only the last makes sense here, since the output can only be `()`. And `put [0]`makes the initial state irrelevant - perhaps remove the `put [0]`.